# Entity Framework selecting distinct from an inner query based on Concat

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The concat works, but the outer distinct query does not. The error is 'string does not contain a definition for 'role_name'... Any idea how to make this work?

```
(from results in ((from pmr in dbContext.project_member_role
                   join r in dbContext.role on pmr.project_member_role_id equals r.role_id
                   where pmr.member_id == memberId
                   select r.role_name)
                   .Concat(from m in dbContext.member
                           join r in dbContext.role on m.portal_role_id equals r.role_id
                           where m.member_id == memberId
                           select r.role_name))
 select results.role_name).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you using a Join from CLR, load you data into seperate entites and act on them accordingly

Comment: thanks for the downvote :/

Comment: `results` is a `string` (you are concatenating 2 `IQueryable<string>`), simply use `select results).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: @jack_c, I didn't down vote you, the only question's I would ever down vote are "Do my homework" or ones that provide no code, as a constellation prize you can have my upvote

Comment: Thank you @Ivan, that worked for me and I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you @johnny_5, I have been trying to figure this out for a long time. I never ask questions without at least giving my best effort. I am relatively new to Entity Framework, and I have to admit I am still baffled. I feel stupid. I have been writing SQL for a long time, so struggling with a problem that would normally take me maybe 10 minutes is extremely frustrating.